# How to disable TestNG in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng

I have some Junit tests but can not get the result with mvn test. I did some research and it shows the problem could be TestNG. So I delete all the testng code and dependencies in the pom file. But when I run the mvn test, "Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator" still shows up. How can I disable that?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since you are mentioning `mvn test` am guessing that you are using the surefire plugin. Surefire plugin unless and until provided with a testng dependency, it by default works with only JUnit. So there's still a TestNG dependency being resolved somewhere in your test project and your test classes are still having TestNG annotations in it.